# Java structure JFrame GUI

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jframe

I am a computer scientist in my first year of my apprenticeship.

In the beginning we started with procedural Java programming, now we have to learn the object oriented Java. To begin with that, we have to program a GUI with some features and something to save some Strings like in a Database.
Anyway, I'm not there yet. I'm still stuck at creating and Structure the GUI. It has everything inside that it needs, but the structure I'm trying to get does not really work.

So here's what I got:

**TestGUI.Java**

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestGui {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ModulGui GUI = new ModulGui();
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("icon.png");
        GUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GUI.setSize(250,350);
        GUI.setIconImage(img.getImage());
        GUI.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        GUI.setResizable(false);
        GUI.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

**ModulGui.java**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.security.PrivateKey;

public class ModulGui extends JFrame {

    private final JLabel LabelModulID;
    private final JLabel LabelModulName;
    private final JLabel LabelStartDatum;

    private final JTextField TextFeldModulId;
    private final JTextField TextFeldModulName;
    private final JTextField TextFeldStartDatum;

    private final JButton ButtonHinzufuegen;
    private final JButton ButtonEntfernen;
    private final JButton ButtonAlleAusgeben;

    public ModulGui(){

        super("Modulliste");

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        GridBagConstraints GuiGrid = new GridBagConstraints();

        LabelModulID = new JLabel("Modul ID");
        LabelModulID.setToolTipText("Bitte Modul ID eintragen.");
        GuiGrid.gridx = 0;
        GuiGrid.gridy = 1;
        add(LabelModulID);

        LabelModulName = new JLabel("Modulname");
        LabelModulName.setToolTipText("Bitte Modulnamen eintragen");
        GuiGrid.gridx = 0;
        GuiGrid.gridy = 2;
        add(LabelModulName);

        LabelStartDatum = new JLabel("Startdatum");
        LabelStartDatum.setToolTipText("Startdatum des Moduls eintragen");
        GuiGrid.gridx = 0;
        GuiGrid.gridy = 3;
        add(LabelStartDatum);

        TextFeldModulId = new JTextField(25);
        GuiGrid.gridx = 0;
        GuiGrid.gridy = 4;
        add(TextFeldModulId);

        TextFeldModulName = new JTextField(25);
        GuiGrid.gridx = 0;
        GuiGrid.gridy = 5;
        add(TextFeldModulName);

        TextFeldStartDatum = new JTextField(25);
        GuiGrid.gridx = 0;
        GuiGrid.gridy = 6;
        add(TextFeldStartDatum);

        ButtonHinzufuegen = new JButton("Hinzufügen");
        GuiGrid.gridx = 0;
        GuiGrid.gridy = 7;
        add(ButtonHinzufuegen);

        ButtonEntfernen = new JButton("Entfernen");
        GuiGrid.gridx = 0;
        GuiGrid.gridy = 8;
        add(ButtonEntfernen);

        ButtonAlleAusgeben = new JButton("Alle Ausgeben");
        GuiGrid.gridx = 0;
        GuiGrid.gridy = 9;
        add(ButtonAlleAusgeben);
    }
}
```

Sorry Maybe the Problem is really easy, but like I said I'm pretty new to programing :D
I also tried it with setBounds and setLayout(null)... Well didn't really work either.

I want to structure my Code as the following:

```
LabelModulID
TextFeldModulID
LabelModulName
TextFeldModulName
LabelStartDatum
TextFeldStartDatum
ButtonHinzufuegen
ButtonEntfernen
ButtonAlleAusgeben
```

Do you guys have an idea of how I could do this?

And does someone know how I could use Objects or something else to store some Modules (Module) like in a Database. Like the class Modulelist and Module.

Thank you guys in advance!!

**//Edit//**

So that's the new code I got with your help. It doesn't look good, but it isn't bad for the second attempt:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.security.PrivateKey;

public class ModulGui extends JFrame {

    public final JPanel panelModulID = new JPanel();
    public final JPanel panelModulName = new JPanel();
    public final JPanel panelStartDatum = new JPanel();
    public final JPanel panelButtons = new JPanel();

    private final JLabel LabelModulID;
    private final JLabel LabelModulName;
    private final JLabel LabelStartDatum;

    private final JTextField TextFeldModulId;
    private final JTextField TextFeldModulName;
    private final JTextField TextFeldStartDatum;

    private final JButton ButtonHinzufuegen;
    private final JButton ButtonEntfernen;
    private final JButton ButtonAlleAusgeben;

    public ModulGui(){

        super("Modulliste");

        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        LabelModulID = new JLabel("Modul ID");
        LabelModulID.setToolTipText("Bitte Modul ID eintragen.");
        panelModulID.add(LabelModulID);

        LabelModulName = new JLabel("Modulname");
        LabelModulName.setToolTipText("Bitte Modulnamen eintragen");
        panelModulName.add(LabelModulName);

        LabelStartDatum = new JLabel("Startdatum");
        LabelStartDatum.setToolTipText("Startdatum des Moduls eintragen");
        panelStartDatum.add(LabelStartDatum);

        TextFeldModulId = new JTextField(25);
        panelModulID.add(TextFeldModulId);

        TextFeldModulName = new JTextField(25);
        panelModulName.add(TextFeldModulName);

        TextFeldStartDatum = new JTextField(25);
        panelStartDatum.add(TextFeldStartDatum);

        ButtonHinzufuegen = new JButton("Hinzufügen");
        panelButtons.add(ButtonHinzufuegen);

        ButtonEntfernen = new JButton("Entfernen");
        panelButtons.add(ButtonEntfernen);

        ButtonAlleAusgeben = new JButton("Alle Ausgeben");
        panelButtons.add(ButtonAlleAusgeben);

        add(panelModulID);
        add(panelModulName);
        add(panelStartDatum);
        add(panelButtons);
    }
}
```

And it gets me this:
[image: Output]

Comment: 1) Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Follow the conventions used in your text book or code example found on the web. 2) Definitely don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). You can download and play with each of the different layout managers. You can also nest panels to achieve your desired layout.

Comment: Thanks for the Tip! Like I wrote, im pretty new to it ^^

Comment: @AndrewThompson Ok, i'll try to do it with a layout Manager... Which one did you use? I would have tried with GroupLayout.

Comment: @AndrewThompson And yes what you did with your example is exactly what I need ^^

Comment: Something to keep in mind when programming in Java is [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html): `FirstWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseVariable`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod(...)` and `ALL_WORDS_UPPER_CASED_CONSTANTS` this way your code will be easier to read and understand by you and others in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ok, i'll try to do it with a layout Manager... Which one did you use? I would have tried with `GroupLayout`.

Ah, therein lies a common error. Few, if any, good layouts are created using a *single* layout. Instead we usually combine them to create the needed GUI.

Take this layout for example:

[image]

It uses a `GridBagLayout` for the 'outer' part, but then puts a (`JPanel` with a) `FlowLayout` in the last row of that GBL to hold the buttons.

[image]

Here is the code used to put it together:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class GUILayout {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    GUILayout() {
        initUI();
    }

    public final void initUI() {
        if (ui!=null) return;

        ui = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4));

        addLabelAndField("Module ID", 5, 0);
        addLabelAndField("Module Name", 15, 1);
        addLabelAndField("Start Datum", 10, 2);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        ui.add(p, gbc);
        p.add(new JButton("Hinzufuegen"));
        p.add(new JButton("Entfernen"));
        p.add(new JButton("Alle Ausgeben"));
    }

    private void addLabelAndField(String labelText, int fieldWidth, int row) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        gbc.gridy = row;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        ui.add(new JLabel(labelText), gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        ui.add(new JTextField(fieldWidth), gbc);
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (Exception useDefault) {
            }
            GUILayout o = new GUILayout();

            JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

            f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
            f.pack();
            f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

            f.setVisible(true);
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I get it. But it's still very complicated if you're new xD I'm trying to understand everything right now, but it's kind of hard to be honest.

Comment: .. creating GUIs that work across multiple OS' requires laying out the components using a layout manager. It won't be easy until you get used to using & combining those layouts. *"I'm trying to understand everything right now"* I've been coding Swing GUIs for (checks watch) almost 20 years now. It's gotten a lot easier, but there are *still* times that it isn't easy to create the effect a GUI needs.

Comment: Yeah definetly... I'm just starting out with it. I have to learn Java in school. To be honest I would prefer python because I want to get into Data Sience and Bots and so on. Anyway, I edited my post, do you think it could be good enough for a starter? ^^

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, you're adding your GUI components directly to the `JFrame`. Instead, you need a `JPanel` to hold all your GUI components and then add that `JPanel` to your `JFrame`

For example:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(button1);
panel.add(button2);
panel.add(label1);

add(panel); // Adds panel to the JFrame
```

If you want to play around with specific layouts, you can check out the [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html). There's also more information on how to use a `JPanel` in the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html).

Comment: Hm ok, i tried that ^^ I Guess i did something wrong xD
i'll try it agin!

Has the JPanel to be private too? I mean you can't call it like this: private final JPanel panel;

Comment: @ItzImmmy Making the panel `private` won't change anything except its accessibility, although it is good practice to have it. You may have forgotten to set the layout of the panel or add it to the `JFrame`.

Comment: @ItzImmmy It just ensures that you've defined the accessibility of a variable in your class.